# MySQL join two tables by a column which needs to be incremented by a number

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to add the number 100000 to all the clients ids in the `clients` table when I'm performing a join. Seems that `(100000 + c.id) AS c.id` works fine in the `SELECT`, but I get an error on the `LEFT JOIN clients c ON p.client_id = (100000 + c.id)' join.

The query looks like this:

`SELECT p.id, p.date, p.document, (100000 + c.id) AS c.id, c.name
FROM payments p
LEFT JOIN clients c ON p.client_id = (100000 + c.id)
WHERE p.date < CURRENT_DATE`

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try remove the tablename from the alias (id and not c.id)

```
SELECT p.id, p.date, p.document, (100000 + c.id) AS  id, c.name
FROM payments p
LEFT JOIN clients c ON p.client_id = 100000 + c.id
WHERE p.date < CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: @Cosmin  i think this is not related at the on condtion but at the fact related to alias ..you have use c.id of alias that is the same as the table.column .. this cause an error on left join

Comment: @Cosmin - scaisEdge is right. You can't use a table alias in a column alias ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ac9dd/2)). And there is nothing wrong in the ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

Is c.id 1 supposed to become 100,001 or 1,000,001? (I know the commas aren't needed. There were just too many zeros for me)

If it should be the first, I have no idea what your problem is. If it is the second, you should concat instead of +

Comment: It has to become 100001. But I solved it doing `ON p.client = c.id + 100000` instead of `ON p.client_id = 100000 + c.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it P.id or p.client_id????

Perhaps change p.client_id to P.id on the join